# LINQ - EXISTS, Reference Parent Field in Subquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm working on creating a dynamic linq expression with an optional where clause containing "exists".

Almost everything about this can be dynamic.  The user can choose to filter only root level nodes or filter both the root and all descendant nodes.  I've mocked up a working example of one of the paths this query takes that is giving me issues.

Example of T-SQL:

```
SELECT 'Child exists', ge.id AS [run_id], aseq.id, aseq.name
FROM group_execution ge
    JOIN automation_sequences aseq ON (aseq.id=ge.automation_sequence_id)
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT ge2.patriarch_id FROM group_execution ge2
        JOIN automation_sequences aseq2 ON (aseq2.id=ge2.automation_sequence_id)
    WHERE aseq2.name LIKE '%test%'
        AND ge2.patriarch_id = ge.patriarch_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ase.patriarch_id FROM automation_sequence_executions ase
        JOIN automation_sequences aseq2 ON (aseq2.id=ase.automation_sequence_id)
    WHERE aseq2.name LIKE '%test%'
        AND ase.patriarch_id = ge.patriarch_id)
```

The problem I'm having is LINQ is giving me an execution plan that looks like this:

```
SELECT 'Child exists', ge.id AS [run_id], aseq.id, aseq.name
FROM group_execution ge
    JOIN automation_sequences aseq ON (aseq.id=ge.automation_sequence_id)
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1
        FROM
        (SELECT ase.patriarch_id FROM automation_sequence_executions ase
            JOIN automation_sequences aseq2 ON (aseq2.id=ase.automation_sequence_id)
        WHERE aseq2.name LIKE '%test%'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ge2.patriarch_id FROM group_execution ge2
            JOIN automation_sequences aseq2 ON (aseq2.id=ge2.automation_sequence_id)
        WHERE aseq2.name LIKE '%test%'
        ) AS sub
    WHERE sub.patriarch_id = ge.patriarch_id)
```

Notice how it's putting the "where" clause outside the union.  This plan is killing the performance of my query.  The first query runs in less than a second but the second takes up to 30 seconds.

I'm having a ton of trouble figuring out how to write the LINQ expression to mimic the first query I have above.

Below is my code so far:

```
//creates first query from group_execution table and does joins
IQueryable<Contract_SeqExecution> result = this.queryGroups(context);

...

//query for children:
IQueryable<ATSM_DAL.App_Data.automation_sequence_executions> tcChildrenRuns = null;
IQueryable<ATSM_DAL.App_Data.group_execution> groupChildrenRuns = null;

if (queryTestCase)
    tcChildrenRuns = (from ase in context.automation_sequence_executions
                      where ase.parent_group_exec_id != null
                      select ase);
if (queryGroup)
    groupChildrenRuns = (from ge in context.group_execution
                         where ge.parent_group_exec_id != null
                         select ge);

//Perform Union All on child results
decendantResults = this.UnionAllTCGroups(tcChildrenRuns, groupChildrenRuns);

//handles dynamic filter, example: aseq2.name LIKE '%test%'
decendantResults = decendantResults.Where(filterExpression);

...

//Perform the EXISTS statement in where clause.  This is the problem code
Expression<Func<Contract_SeqExecution, bool>> childFilter = r => decendantResults.AsExpandable().Any(c => c.patriarchId == r.patriarchId);
childFilter = childFilter.Or(filterExpression);
result = result.AsExpandable().Where(childFilter);
```